# Problema al actualizar elemento en un tableview

Tags: java, javafx

Estoy trabajando en un código y me gustaria saber como puedo actualizar los elementos de un `tableview`.

Es decir, yo tengo mi código con un método `editar` que me edita los componentes seleccionados de dicha tabla. Por ejemplo, tengo un elemento que se llama `prueba` y contiene un `int` con valor 6. Yo lo edito y lo llamo `pruebaedit`, cambio el valor del `int` a 5 y me edita ese elemento en el `ObservableList`.

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero cuando yo le doy a salvar me edita la lista pero en la tabla se siguen mostrando los datos antiguos.

Me gustaríaa hacer un update a la tabla y que cada vez que edite un elemento se actualizen los valores de este elemento en la tabla y los muestre actualizados.

Comment: Se que llego un poco tarde, pero estaría bien ver el código que tienes, para poder saber de donde partimos para encontrar una solución.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar creando un objeto `TableView<T>` y pasárselo como valor a tu `TableView` con datos.

Por ejemplo:

```
TableView<Producto> table = new TableView<>();
ArrayList<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<>();

//Se agregan elementos a tu TableView
table.getItems().addAll(productos);
table.getColumns().addAll(nombre, clave, tiuni, descrip, exis, precio);

/**
 * Método que actualiza información de TableView
 * @return botón de actualizar
 */
public Button bActualizar() {
    actualizar.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() { //actualizar es tipo Button
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            TableView<Producto> pr = new TableView<>();
            table = pr;  //TableView vacío para que no duplique
            //Llamada al método para mostrar table actualizado
        }
    });
    return actualizar;
}
```